# Facing Issue While Upgrading EKS Using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

Getting an below error while doing terraform apply, can you guys help me.

I am updating from 1.19 to 1.20 and getting below error.

module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this[0]: Creating...
Error: error creating EKS Cluster (produsw): InvalidParameterException: unsupported Kubernetes version
{
RespMetadata: {
StatusCode: 400,
RequestID: "35df498d-77cf-4412-9bf8-ff7daa54de66"
},
ClusterName: "produsw2",
Message_: "unsupported Kubernetes version"
}
on .terraform/modules/eks/cluster.tf line 9, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this":
9: resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {

I have checked all the versions for eks but no luck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are stuck on [unsupported EKS version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html) and the next hop version is also not supported by `AWS EKS`.
Last supported version of `AWS EKS` is `1.21`.

In that case I would recommend:

1. Upgrade to `1.21` directly (not sure if this will be allowed in `terraform` or `AWS Console` since they mention you need to upgrade `1` version at a time)
2. If first option will not work please contact `AWS support` since there is no document that I can find about such case.

In worst case scenario you will need to setup new cluster along with existing one and move all your workloads to fresh cluster.

Comment: Thanks, but I have done deployment on the stage environment with 1.20  and it was working fine.

Comment: I have done changed version for aws EKS to 1.21 and it's working now, actually created new cluster and it got worked. Thanks for your help and support.